# CSS atributo value no nulo

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente `select` con los siguientes `style`

```
select:valid{
    font-weight:bold;
}

select:invalid{
    font-weight:normal;
}

<select id="maxRows" required>
   <option value="">Registros</option>
   <option value="10">10 filas</option>
   <option value="20">20 filas</option>
   <option value="50">50 filas</option>
</select>
```

el CSS cambia la font a `bold` para el caso de que el `select` tenga una `option` valida, es decir un valor que sea distinto de vacio. Funciona bien, el problema es que solo funciona si el campo `select` tiene el atributo `required` y necesito crear otros `select` sin ese atributo.

Como puedo consultar un value distinto de vacio o nulo con css? Intente usar este para reemplazar el `:valid` pero no funciona.

```
select[value="*"]{
  font-weight:bold;
}

select:invalid{
    font-weight:normal;
}

<select id="maxRows">
   <option value="">Registros</option>
   <option value="10">10 filas</option>
   <option value="20">20 filas</option>
   <option value="50">50 filas</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Creo que el ```option``` no se puede darle estilo con CSS.  Su estilo es propio del navegador.

Comment: Mejor crea tu propio estilo de menú desplegable propio. Te recomiendo ver este para una idea mejor: https://api-apises-version-1.netlify.app/ Usa CSS y JavaScript

Comment: no quiero darle style al option, es al select que quiero que se modifique cuando hay algun valor seleccionado. Se que se puede hacer con javascript, pero no quiero hacerlo con eso

Comment: @MTDesigner si no puedes o no quieres usar la validación propia de HTML, tienes que usar JS. Al no hacer requerido el selector no hay una propiedad que pueda confirmarte que se selecciono un valor para poder aplicar estilos sin JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desafortunadamente, en la [especificación](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element) del elemento `select` se indica:

> **Validación de Restricciones**: Si el elemento tiene especificado su atributo `required` ...

Es decir, cualquier pseudo-clase de validación no funcionará si el elemento no es obligatorio.

Sin embargo, la alternativa con javascript no es tan gravosa:

```css
select[is-selected]{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="this.toggleAttribute('is-selected',selectedIndex>0)">
   <option value="">Registros</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```